Comma usage in compound-complex sentence
Which sentence is more appropriate?

Even if the budget allows for certain expenses, and we can prioritize some projects, we cannot fund them all.

or

Even if the budget allows for certain expenses and we can prioritize some projects, we cannot fund them all.


There is inherent ambiguity: << Even if A is true and it thus follows that B is true, C [regrettably] remains true >> vs < Even if A is true and B is also true, C [regrettably] remains true >>. It probably doesn't alter the overall thrust much in this particular case, but it might in other cases. I'd say comma insertion is less important than disambiguation (by rephrasing). // Ambiguity often arises as 'and' is used both to show causation and merely simultaneity (as well as anteriority).

The commas are optional but preferred. They help to mark the boundaries of the coordinates.

The fact that being able of prioritizing projects allows a greater freedom in the way of funding more projects, shows that "and we … projects" has concessive force; but along this line of thinking it seems better to repeat the conjunctive phrase "even if".

Even if the budget allows for certain expenses and even if we can prioritize some projects, we cannot fund them all.

However, "and" by itself seems to be used sometimes in English with special concessive force, and in that case the comma is necessary as a certain emphasis is being put on this concession.

Even if the police is rather inefficient, and we know that they could become even more inefficient, we put our trust in them for our security. (It seems that in the spoken language "and" would be spoken with more emphasis.)

The first form (with its comma) is then acceptable (granted special concessive force is reckoned to be part of the conjunctive clause), but the second appears wanting in definiteness.
